# Всегда ли слово "неплановый" пишется слитно?

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфография, грамматика, частица-не, слитно-раздельно

В разных контекстах видел различное написание слова *"плановый"* с частицей *"не"*. Насколько мне удалось понять, *"неплановый"* надо писать слитно в большинстве случаев. Но хотелось бы узнать, есть ли исключительные ситуации?

Например, должно ли писаться слитно в следующей фразе, которую я встретил в официальном документе:

> процедура согласования не плановых отпусков.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Процедура согласования неплановых отпусков**
Здесь однозначно - слитно.
Причина раздельного написания, возможно, в том, что многие программы-корректоры  не знают этого слова и рекомендуют (ошибочно) раздельное написание. 
Однако тут надо руководствоваться не мнением спелл-чекеров, а достаточно простым правилом, которое (если опустить некоторые оговорки, не имеющие прямого отношения к употреблению конкретного слова) предписывает использование слитного написания всегда, когда с помощью частицы вводится новое понятие.
Напротив, раздельно с прилагательным частица "не" пишется в случаях, если имеется явное или подразумеваемое противопоставление.

В рассматриваемом случае ни о каком "противопоставлении" речи быть не может, а факт закрепления нового понятия "неплановый" представляется очевидным. К тому же "неплановый" вполне может быть заменено на синоним "внеплановый".

Подробнее - тут. (§57, особенно пп. 2 и 3). 
http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=77

Более или менее правдоподобный контекст для случая, требующего раздельного написания, можно только сконструировать, в реальных текстах он вряд ли встретится. 
Но вот пример такой "реконструкции": *Мы рассматриваем не плановые отпуска, а предоставленные работнику вне графика в силу особых обстоятельств. Вот с прцедурой предоставления таких отпусков мы и хотим разобраться*. Бредовато, конечно, но пример изобретен исключительно для демонстрации контекста, требующего заведомо раздельного написания.